# Error with giving a value to int

Tags: c#

I have made a programm in c#.
In the code I've made an `int` called: `Paying`
but when I try to give it a value, it says the following error:

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method or
>   property
>   'Mc_Donalds.Program.Paying'

any suggestions on what I should do?

```
public int Paying;

// Select what meal you want
Console.WriteLine("To order please type the number infront of the item.");
int Keuze = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

if (Keuze == 1)
{
    Paying = 5; 
}

else if (Keuze == 2)
{
     Paying = 3.50;
}

else if (Keuze == 3)
{
     Paying = 1;
}

else if (Keuze == 4)
{
     Paying = 6;
}
```

Comment: Show the code involved.

Comment: Need to see your code for any help

Comment: Normally those errors mean youre trying to call an instance method, but without specifying an instance.

Comment: Is this code in the main method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd think your method that does this is static while your int (Paying is not)

Comment: In addition there is error in `Paying = 3.50;` as Paying is int

Comment: i'm aware of that and already fixed the error thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways with which you can access a variable in object oriented world

You should create an object for the `class` where you declare this variable or make this Field a `static` field.

The variable in question is `Paying`.

try to change the declaration of `Paying` from `public int Paying;` to something like this

```
public static int Paying;
```

Then use it as `Program.Paying = 5` or `Program.Paying = 3.5` etc assuming your class name in `Program`